# Xcode build number for new version

Tags: ios, xcode, build

Hope it's not off topic question. So usually I use my version for app:

- 1.0
- 1.1
- 1.2

So let's say I uploaded 50 builds to iTunes for the version 1.0

So it means that latest version of app has kind of 1.0.50 (indicating that the last build is 50)

So my question is should I bump build number for new version 1.1 to make it 1.1.1 or do I need to use 1.1.51 because previous build was 50.

Doest it make sense, is there any rules about it? I know that technically there is no worry about it, but if we say about some system and about team that usually want to check latest build or kind of maybe we should follow with some build number rules.

Comment: As long as each new build number is higher. `1.1.1` is higher than `1.0.x` so you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I use following:

```
AppName_<Major>.<Minor>.<Patch/Upgrade>.<BuildNo>
```

**Major** - Major version is a definite release of the product. It increased when there are significant changes in functionality.

**Minor** - Minor version is incremented when only new features or major bug fixes have been added.

**Upgrade/Patch** - Upgrade refers to the replacement of a product with a newer version of product.It is incremented only when upgrade is provided on designated major release.Patch version starts with 0 and incremented only when bug has been resolved.

**Build No** - Build Number is incremented when new build is created.